# How to run a shell script from an HTML page?

Tags: javascript, html, shell

I want to make a single button and an input box on an html page `input.html`, which when clicked should execute a shell script `test.sh`. The shell script should take that input box string as parameter. The shell script creates an html file `out.html` (I have created the shell script, which when takes an input string, produces an html file), which then I want to show on original html page `input.html`.

How can I do this ? Assume everything is running locally i.e. no server thing here.

Comment: to execute a shell script from an html page, you would definitely need a server.

Comment: You can't do this without a server doing some kind of preprocessing.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try loading that from server side language (like PHP)

```
<?php
if ($_GET['run']) {
  # This code will run if ?run=true is set.
  exec("/path/to/name.sh");
}
?>

<!-- This link will add ?run=true to your URL, myfilename.php?run=true -->
<a href="?run=true">Click Me!</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Browsers won't allow that, that would break the Internet and make hackers very happy if it was possible, yet this can be done with Firefox/Chrome addons or IE activeX controls.

Normally, websites sites [that](https://www.meteor.com/install) [want](https://getcomposer.org/download/) [you](https://github.com/npm/npm#fancy-install-unix) [to](https://github.com/creationix/nvm#install-script) [run](http://rvm.io/rvm/install#quick-guided-install) [a](https://gist.github.com/btm/6700524#easy-one-line-chef-installation-for-all-platforms-except-windows) script on your terminal will give you a command like this one that you would copy and paste to your terminal:

```
curl -sS https://example.com/script.sh | sh
```

### Examples:

```
# meteor.js
curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sudo sh

# node.js
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup | bash -

# Composer
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```