# How to call a .sh file function through html GUI?

Tags: java

I am using HTMl to develop a GUI where in I want to give a call to a function existing in .sh file.

Can any one please suggest suitable option as I tried to call function in different ways but didn't worked out.

Comment: What will be the steps for above to execute?

Comment: Do you mean a Unix shell-script file?  And is it on the server or the client?

Comment: Hope you have checked these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27012272/how-to-run-a-shell-script-from-an-html-page

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/executing-linuxunix-commands-from-web-page-part-i.html

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6235785/run-a-shell-script-with-an-html-button

Comment: You tagged Java. Probably you have Java code in the back end. Run the shell script there. Call the Java function from HTML through From submission or some AJAX call.

Comment: Yes. I have Java code in the back end. I will try for this.

Comment: hi All,I have tried for below code  ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("Tasks/SA Autodeployment/copyScript.sh");
  
   Process p = pb.start();
   BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
   String line = null;
   while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
   {
      System.out.println(line);
   }                                                                                                    but getting this exception Cannot run program "/Tasks/SA Autodeployment/copyScript.sh": CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this from HTML. HTML describes what a page looks like; it doesn't "execute" anything.

You might be able to translate your shell script into JavaScript, which can be embedded in an HTML page, depending on what the shell script does.

If you have a web server, [CGI](http://www.team2053.org/docs/bashcgi/gettingstarted.html) is a protocol (not a network protocol) which allows the web server to run specially-written executables (including scripts) in response to requests to certain web addresses. You can then include a form that submits to an address that triggers your script, or send the request from JavaScript.