# Run a shell script from Greasemonkey?

Tags: greasemonkey

I would like to add a button on a webpage that will execute a command line (let's say a simple `echo "The HTML page title is: ...";`), with parameters taken from the webpage.

I'm almost sure it won't be allowed using plain JS (because of security issues) but is there a Greasemonkey way to do so?

I didn't see anything that would match in the [greasemonkey API doc](https://wiki.greasespot.net/Greasemonkey_Manual:API), but I still have hope there can be a way to do that (besides using a [localhost PHP script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27012272/how-to-run-a-shell-script-from-an-html-page) loaded by `GM_getResourceURL`: I would like to avoid asking the GM script users to setup a local server first; note that [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30010014/run-a-php-script-or-anything-similar-from-greasemonkey-tampermonkey) requires a local server too)...

Comment: Can't do it. And if you could, the lead GM developer would shut it down as soon as he learned of it.  You need to write an extension to do this.

Comment: @BrockAdams Why would he? Users are supposed to know that accepting an external user script is a threat, that why there's a pop-up showing a warning and the JS source code.

Comment: Don't believe me?  Search the GM GitHub and then take it up with him.